# Git for Windows error Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh

OS - Windows 7.
I installed Source Tree, and I have account on Bitbucket.
I generated SSH key in Source Tree, saved public key as `test.pub` and private key as `test_private.ppk` in `.ssh` folder, and added private key in Pageant.
Also I copied ssh key and saved it in Bitbucket settings.
When I use Source Tree interface, commits and pushes work just fine but when I try to use console, I get an error `Permission denied (publickey)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

What's the problem?

**UPD**
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to tell `ssh` where to find your keys using `-i` switch to `ssh` or rather using `ssh_config` so even `git` will know them.

Comment: Can you explain me in details what I should do?

Comment: have you tried `ssh-add test_private`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell ssh where to find your keys using -i switch to ssh or rather using ssh_config so even git will know them.

```
ssh -i test_private.ppk -T git@bitbucket.org
```

should work work for you. Adding the line

```
IdentityFile test_private.ppk
```

to your `ssh_config` should solve the issue for both cases.

Comment: Where can I find `ssh_config` ?

Comment: post verbose log `ssh -vvvi test_private.ppk -T git@bitbucket.org` to edited question and I will be (hopefully) able to tell about your installation.

Comment: certainly you need to update the path to your `test_private.ppk` if it is not in current directory. Where is your `ssh_config` should be clear from manual page for `ssh_config` in your installation, but is should be `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: I didn't install `ssh` in some special way, I installed only Source Tree, so I have only `.ssh` folder in my folder in `Users` folder.